# What the equivalent of the ASP.NET Login controls in Java web frameworks world?

Tags: java, authentication, controls, web-frameworks

Which Java web framework (if any) has functionality that comes close to the [ASP.NET Login controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)?  What's the recommended way to provide login, authentication, new user registration, etc in the Java web world?  Are there reusable libraries for this? I can't imagine everyone rolls their own.

I'm coming from ASP.NET and trying to figure out how to get things done in Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Scooter framework](http://scooterframework.com/docs/security.html) provides some basic login authentication control and views which can give you a quick start.